# Network traffic generator / simulator

Tags: linux, windows, networking, network-traffic

Does anyone know of a traffic generator that can generate or simulate network traffic for example http, ftp, smtp, instant messaging and voice plus video over IP traffic. I need the different traffic profiles to test the impact of security of real-time QoS traffic. If possible the traffic generator will permit for one to chose a bandwidth percentage a profile is to take up.

I have tried numerous ones including iperf, jperf, Ntttcp and the all hog the links bandwidth with one traffic profile. So I'm ideally after a generator with flexibility not a stress testing tool.

Comment: Well, Linux has the `tc` command, which allows traffic control to a granular scale (want to emulate loading your website on satellite connection from the Antarctic? This is your dude). You're probably looking for some GUI tools though, so I guess it's not what you're really looking for.

Answer (score 2):

JMeter can be configured to do some distributed testing

http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_distributed_testing_step_by_step.pdf

You could create a "Thread group" for each traffic profile that you want to test

Answer (score 1):

Yes, look at the tools from Ixia Communications or Spirent.   Both specialize in network test tools on both a functional and performance basis.....including the ability to generate just the types of traffic flows to test QOS that you describe.

Of the offerings from both vendors I am partial to IxChariot from Ixia.   Full disclosure: A little over a decade ago I worked for the company the originated the technology which underpins IxChariot, including developing the first training class for Chariot.    IxChariot is also a full software solution where many of the other elements include hardware components.   It can also be had on a lease term basis.

Answer (score 0):

I've only ever heard of network nightmare, a brand name.